# Deploying Create React App to a subdirectory but make API calls to parent path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, create-react-app

I'm deploying my Create React App to a specific path in a larger non-React webapp. For example, I will say the webapp path is www.example.com and the React app is deployed at www.example.com/react/

I have done this by setting the "homepage" property in package.json of the React app to `"homepage": "/react"`, which does properly serve the static files from the /react/ path on my server.

However, when I make API calls from my react app, they go to `/react/api/etc` instead of `/api/etc`.

I can configure axios to use a hardcoded base path of `www.example.com`, but I deploy this to multiple environments with different URLs and need a solution that doesn't rely on a hardcoded value.

I could also write a workaround on the server side, but it would be less clean / mess with my logging and request statistics.

I would love a clean solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you used the `window.location` property in your axios config object:

```
{
  baseURL: `${location.hostname}/api/` // or window.location.hostname
}
```